# Diferenciar eventos de Usuario y de la programación en un control checkbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas estoy haciendo un desarrollo el cual tiene un formulario de Configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada vez que este formulario se cargar; se debe leer un archivo xml en donde se guarda la configuración:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<conf>
  <urls>
    <u1>http://avisistema-3.pro/</u1>
    <u2>http://avisistema-2.pro/</u2>
    <u3>https://mail.avipacinc.com/</u3>
    <u4>https://mail.google.com/</u4>
    <u5>https://www.google.com/</u5>
  </urls>
  <adm>false</adm>
  <protect>
    <enable>false</enable>
    <hash></hash>
  </protect>
</conf>
```

***Cual es la funcionalidad con la que tengo problemas:***

Con la de proteger la configuración; se supone que cuando le de click al checkbox ***Proteger Configuración por Contraseña:*** y este cambia de estado checked a uncheked o viceversa: debe abrir un dialogo en donde se introduce la contraseña, lo cual hasta este punto ocurre perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Cual es el problema especifico de la funcionalidad:***

Si en algún momento la configuración fue protegida ***ANTES***; al momento en que nuevamente se cargar el formulario de configuración y programáticamente se ejecuta la siguiente linea de código:

```
if (protectNode.Name == "enable" && protectNode.InnerText == "true")
{

    checkBox2.Checked = true;

}
```

Nota: esta linea de código es parte del script que muestra la configuración actual en el archivo o hace el volcado del xml al formulario.

Entonces se Esta Activando el Evento y se abre el dialogo de colocar contraseña, por lo tanto no se esta diferenciando entre el evento programático y el evento de usuario!

***¿Cómo puedo resolver esta situación?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el sitio en ingles encontré una sugerencia de como poder controlar este tipo de escenario mediante programación:

1. Crear una propiedad en la clase boleana llamada flag:

```
bool flag = true;
```

2. Al Ejecutar la asignación programática pasar el flag al false:

```
if (protectNode.Name == "enable" && protectNode.InnerText == "true")
{

    flag = false;
    checkBox2.Checked = true;
    flag = true;
    break;

}
```

3. En el Evento debemos avaluar flag, con lo cual determinamos si viene de un evento del usuario o de la programación:

```
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (flag) //evaluación
    {

        //Programación que hacer cuando el usuario da click al checkbox

    }
            
}
```

***Nota:*** no estoy seguro de que sea la forma mas eficiente o correcta de solucionarlo, pero de momento funciona.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9870593/17161735